# Mixed content (float || unicode) for database column

Tags: python, database-design, sqlalchemy

For sake of simplicity let's say I have a questionare.

Each answer gains a score.

Some questions are *qualitative* so user must choose between one of the text answers.

**Q: what's your fav pet?**

1. cat [1 point]
2. dog [2 points]
3. caiman [3 points]

Answering *dog* I get 2 points.

Some questions are *quantitative* so user inputs a number and gets scoring with linear interpolation:

**How much beer liters do you drink in a day?**

1. 0 [0 points]
2. 1 [1 point]
3. 3 [5 points]

If I answer *2 liters* I get **3 points**.

Now I use sqlalchemy and have a table with an answer each row:

```
questions
    id PK
    name String
    quantitative Bool

answers
    id Integer PK
    id_question Integer FK
    value String
```

and cast `answers.value` to float each time I have to deal with it as a number for interpolation and so on.

1. I could change column name `value` to `_value` and make getter and setter functions for `answer.value` that casts each time to float `answer._value` if question is numeric (`answer.question.quantitative` is `True`)
2. I could have separate columns in answer for textual and numeric values (like `value` and `text`, I will have no millions of records anyway)
3. Or...

What is supposed to be more efficient and easy to use?

Please consider SQLAlchemy magic that takes care of a lot of the dirty work, I'd like to keep it that simple.

---

*Edit*:

Since *beer example* could be misleading I integrate with another:

**Q: how many money do you give in charity in USD?**

1. 0 [0 point]
2. 10 [1 point]
3. 100 [2 points]

Like for *pets & beer question* I have answer values `"0"`, `"10"`, `"100"` stored in database as strings in `answers.value` column so to interpolate values to get score for answer `50` I have all the time to cast `answers.value` to float.

Here's where I have mixed content type in the same db column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick and dirty solution I would suggest at least using two different columns to store different answers. You can also add a CHECK constraint to the database to ensure that exactly one of them is used for any row and the other is NULL. Than do the quick-n-dirty code to calculate total `Test` score.

### The alternative

The idea is build the proper object model, map it to RDMBS and the question does not need to be asked. Also I expect that when using [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html), the resulting DB schema would be almost identical to the current implementation (you can see the model when you run the script with the option `echo=True`):

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    text VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE answer_options (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    question_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    value INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    text VARCHAR, 
    input INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(question_id) REFERENCES questions (id)
)

CREATE TABLE answers (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    question_id INTEGER, 
    test_id INTEGER, 
    answer_option_id INTEGER, 
    answer_input INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(question_id) REFERENCES questions (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(answer_option_id) REFERENCES answer_options (id), 
    --FOREIGN KEY(test_id) REFERENCES tests (id)
)
```

The code below is a complete working script that shows both the object model, its mapping to the database and the usage scenarios. As it is designed, the model is easily extendable with other types of questions/answers without any impact on existing classes. Basically you get less hacky and more flexible code simply because you have an object model which properly reflects your case. The code is below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, SmallInteger, String, ForeignKey, Table, Index
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

# Configure test data SA
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = session.query_property()

class _BaseMixin(object):
    """ Just a helper mixin class to set properties on object creation.  
    Also provides a convenient default __repr__() function, but be aware that 
    also relationships are printed, which might result in loading relations.
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s(%s)>" % (self.__class__.__name__, 
            ', '.join('%s=%r' % (k, self.__dict__[k]) 
                for k in sorted(self.__dict__) if '_sa_' != k[:4] and '_backref_' != k[:9])
            )

### AnswerOption hierarchy
class AnswerOption(Base, _BaseMixin):
    """ Possible answer options (choice or any other configuration).  """
    __tablename__ = u'answer_options'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    question_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('questions.id'), nullable=False)
    value = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    type = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type}

class AnswerOptionChoice(AnswerOption):
    """ A possible answer choice for the question.  """
    text = Column(String, nullable=True) # when mapped to single-table, must be NULL in the DB
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'choice'}

class AnswerOptionInput(AnswerOption):
    """ A configuration entry for the input-type of questions.  """
    input = Column(Integer, nullable=True) # when mapped to single-table, must be NULL in the DB
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'input'}

### Question hierarchy
class Question(Base, _BaseMixin):
    """ Base class for all types of questions.  """
    __tablename__ = u'questions'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String, nullable=False)
    type = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
    answer_options = relationship(AnswerOption, backref='question')
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type}

    def get_answer_value(self, answer):
        """ function to get a value of the answer to the question.  """
        raise Exception('must be implemented in a subclass')

class QuestionChoice(Question):
    """ Single-choice question.  """
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'choice'}

    def get_answer_value(self, answer):
        assert isinstance(answer, AnswerChoice)
        assert answer.answer_option in self.answer_options, "Incorrect choice"
        return answer.answer_option.value

class QuestionInput(Question):
    """ Input type question.  """
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'input'}

    def get_answer_value(self, answer):
        assert isinstance(answer, AnswerInput)
        value_list = sorted([(_i.input, _i.value) for _i in self.answer_options])
        if not value_list:
            raise Exception("no input is specified for the question {0}".format(self))
        if answer.answer_input <= value_list[0][0]:
            return value_list[0][1]
        elif answer.answer_input >= value_list[-1][0]:
            return value_list[-1][1]
        else: # interpolate in the range:
            for _pos in range(len(value_list)-1):
                if answer.answer_input == value_list[_pos+1][0]:
                    return value_list[_pos+1][1]
                elif answer.answer_input < value_list[_pos+1][0]:
                    # interpolate between (_pos, _pos+1)
                    assert (value_list[_pos][0] != value_list[_pos+1][0])
                    return value_list[_pos][1] + (value_list[_pos+1][1] - value_list[_pos][1]) * (answer.answer_input - value_list[_pos][0]) / (value_list[_pos+1][0] - value_list[_pos][0])
        assert False, "should never reach here"

### Answer hierarchy
class Answer(Base, _BaseMixin):
    """ Represents an answer to the question.  """
    __tablename__ = u'answers'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
    question_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('questions.id'), nullable=True) # when mapped to single-table, must be NULL in the DB
    question = relationship(Question)
    test_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tests.id'), nullable=True) # @todo: decide if allow answers without a Test
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type}

    def get_value(self):
        return self.question.get_answer_value(self)

class AnswerChoice(Answer):
    """ Represents an answer to the *Choice* question.  """
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'choice'}
    answer_option_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('answer_options.id'), nullable=True) 
    answer_option = relationship(AnswerOption, single_parent=True)

class AnswerInput(Answer):
    """ Represents an answer to the *Choice* question.  """
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'input'}
    answer_input = Column(Integer, nullable=True) # when mapped to single-table, must be NULL in the DB

### other classes (Questionnaire, Test) and helper tables
association_table = Table('questionnaire_question', Base.metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('questionnaire_id', Integer, ForeignKey('questions.id')),
    Column('question_id', Integer, ForeignKey('questionnaires.id'))
)
_idx = Index('questionnaire_question_u_nci', 
            association_table.c.questionnaire_id, 
            association_table.c.question_id, 
            unique=True)

class Questionnaire(Base, _BaseMixin):
    """ Questionnaire is a compilation of questions.  """
    __tablename__ = u'questionnaires'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    # @note: could use relationship with order or even add question number
    questions = relationship(Question, secondary=association_table)

class Test(Base, _BaseMixin):
    """ Test is a 'test' - set of answers for a given questionnaire. """
    __tablename__ = u'tests'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # @todo: add user name or reference
    questionnaire_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('questionnaires.id'), nullable=False)
    questionnaire = relationship(Questionnaire, single_parent=True)
    answers = relationship(Answer, backref='test')
    def total_points(self):
        return sum(ans.get_value() for ans in self.answers)

# -- end of model definition --

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# -- insert test data --
print '-' * 20 + ' Insert TEST DATA ...'
q1 =  QuestionChoice(text="What is your fav pet?")
q1c1 = AnswerOptionChoice(text="cat", value=1, question=q1)
q1c2 = AnswerOptionChoice(text="dog", value=2, question=q1)
q1c3 = AnswerOptionChoice(text="caiman", value=3)
q1.answer_options.append(q1c3)
a1 = AnswerChoice(question=q1, answer_option=q1c2)
assert a1.get_value() == 2
session.add(a1)
session.flush()

q2 =  QuestionInput(text="How many liters of beer do you drink a day?")
q2i1 = AnswerOptionInput(input=0, value=0, question=q2)
q2i2 = AnswerOptionInput(input=1, value=1, question=q2)
q2i3 = AnswerOptionInput(input=3, value=5)
q2.answer_options.append(q2i3)

# test interpolation routine
_test_ip = ((-100, 0),
            (0, 0),
            (0.5, 0.5),
            (1, 1),
            (2, 3),
            (3, 5),
            (100, 5)
)
a2 = AnswerInput(question=q2, answer_input=None)
for _inp, _exp in _test_ip:
    a2.answer_input = _inp
    _res = a2.get_value()
    assert _res == _exp, "{0}: {1} != {2}".format(_inp, _res, _exp)
a2.answer_input = 2
session.add(a2)
session.flush()

# create a Questionnaire and a Test
qn = Questionnaire(name='test questionnaire')
qn.questions.append(q1)
qn.questions.append(q2)
session.add(qn)
te = Test(questionnaire=qn)
te.answers.append(a1)
te.answers.append(a2)
assert te.total_points() == 5
session.add(te)
session.flush()

# -- other tests --
print '-' * 20 + ' TEST QUERIES ...'
session.expunge_all() # clear the session cache
a1 = session.query(Answer).get(1)
assert a1.get_value() == 2 # @note: will load all dependant objects (question and answer_options) automatically to compute the value
a2 = session.query(Answer).get(2)
assert a2.get_value() == 3 # @note: will load all dependant objects (question and answer_options) automatically to compute the value
te = session.query(Test).get(1)
assert te.total_points() == 5
```

I hope that this version of the code answers all the questions asked in the comments.

Comment: On the 3th time I'm reading your answer I'm starting to figure out how it works but still  have not clear which tables with which colums I'd end up with. In the quick-n-dirty solution you suggest (and I already implemented) I have 3 tables: *Question* (with quantitative / qualitative bool column), *Answers* (with `value` column for quantitatives and `description` for qualitatives), and *Score* (with `value` column holding `score` for qualitative questions or `input` for quantitative, according to `Question.quantitative). It works but I admit it's misleading. +1 anyway

Comment: @neurino: see Edit-1. If you have not used inheritance with ORM tools like SA before, there might be some learning curve, but IMO it is well worth it. If I find more time, I will make the code a working example.

Comment: thank you, I'm new to inheritance with ORM but I'm fine with learning

Comment: ok, see the full working example. hope it matches your model and gives you a kick-start...

Comment: thank you so much for the code, it's now clear to me about tables and `polymorphic_on` stuff, your code runs smoothly. I hope you get more and more upvotes for this

Answer (score 3):

What makes this needlessly complex is trying to optimize the quantitive answers.

It's multiple choice.  Treat the quantitative answer as if it were qualitative. Carry the "points" as a separate attribute of each answer.

And yes, there will be ("3 liters", 3) in the database.  And yes, to a thinking person it may seem redundant.

But for software purposes, it works out well to consider all answers qualitative and keep any quantitative mapping entirely separated.

---

Edit.  Don't store the answer as a number.  It's simply wrong.

> Like for pets & beer question I have answer values "0", "10", "100" stored in database as strings in answers.value column.

Correct.

> to interpolate values to get score for answer 50 I have all the time to cast answers.value to float.

Incorrect.

Look them up just the same way you handle the pets.  It's a simple join.  Do everything the way you do pets.  Treat all data as "qualitative".   One simple rule; not two rules.  That's the correct and standard solution.

Comment: I get your point but my main issue is having the part with data to be interpolated "3 liters" as a string, I'll update my question with a better example. Thank you

Comment: @S.Lott: sorry but I can't understand when you say _incorrect_ about me doing interpolation to get intermediate values: I **do need** to do interpolation on quantitative, the system works this way so I simply can't act the same as qualitative (pets). I'm ending having 2 columns each answer a `value` of type `float` and a `description` of type `string` and use one or the other according to `question.quantitative`. It's redundant and I was asking if it's a good approach or there are alternatives. Thanks for your time

Comment: @neurino: "It's redundant".  No.  You have two different kinds of data in one table; you need both columns.  "I was asking if it's a good approach or there are alternatives."  I'm giving you the alternative.  Don't keep two kinds of data in one table.  Keep all the data as if it is qualitative and look up **all** quantitative score values.  One kind of data is simpler than two kinds of data.

Comment: @S.Lott: what do you mean with "look up **all** quantitative score values" I wish I can accept your answer but can't figure how does it work. Can you please post an example for database answers entries for my _charity_ question and what to pass to a `interpolate(answered_value) -> score` function for `answered_value == 50`?

Comment: @neurino: "look up all quantitative score values" means do a JOIN between the qualitative code and the quantitative value.  If you want to insist that some qualitative values are "quantitative", include a "quantitative" flag in the answers; also the code and the value might  be the same in this case.  `interpolate(answered_value) -> score` is a JOIN with the answer table to translate the answered value to the score.  It's done always the same for qualitative as well as quantitative.  Here's the idea: there is no "quantitative" data.  It's all qualitative.  Life is simpler.

Comment: @S.Lott: sorry but here you are wrong: I'm not making my life harder, 2 different kinds of questions are part of the commitment, questions and answer examples are a simplification, I have to deal with scientific data. Moreover there's already a _quantitative_ flag in question table, no need to add for each answer.

Comment: @S.Lott:  Simply the user has two scenarios, in some cases its score comes from a performance value (for example the hydraulic power of a hot-water heater and score comes from a performance scale i.e `1000W -> -1, 800W -> 3, 300W -> 5` and if user enters `850W` its score is `2`), in other cases its score comes from a choice (for example you have air conditioned or not `absent -> -1, present -> 3`).

Comment: @neurino: Two different kinds of questions doesn't mean you have to create a complex design.  Both kinds of questions are handled by one design.  One design: it uses ONLY qualitative answer lookups.  In all cases the score comes from a lookup.

Comment: @S.Lott: I wish you can show me a practical example in any language on how to handle interpolation with *only* qualitative answers in a no tricky way (i.e. keeping on casting strings to floats that's how I had things working until I asked for the question). Thanks for your time.

Comment: @neurino: "so to interpolate values to get score for answer 50".  You don't.  You **add** "qualitative answer = 50, score = 50" to the database so that **all** answers are in the database.  It's trivial to do this in the rare case when a question permits the user to provide an answer that't not already in the database.  Then **everything** is done one way -- qualitative answers and scores.

Comment: @S.Lott: there are thousand of hot-water heaters on the market, with .1W differences in power each, so should I add 1000s answers? Please... your answer does not fit my question, not a problem to me but don't try to convince me of the contrary :)

Comment: @neurino: Yes.  That's the way it's done.  1000's of answers each used by one question is precisely how this is handled.  You don't have to like the right answer.  I'm just telling you how it's commonly done.

Comment: @S.Lott: this is **not** how it's commonly done... (given it's a common situation). It's redundant and instable (I'd have to change 100s of answers just for changing a single score)

Comment: @neurino: Some of the questions have a limited set of answers.  They can select from the available.  Some of the questions have an unlimited set of answers; they user's answer is added to the database as yet another answer.  For limited ("qualitative") they select from a list.  For unlimited ("quantitative") they enter data without selecting from a list and the user's answer is inserted into the answers table.

Comment: @S.Lott: again: so if the committee wants to change a score rating from `3` to `4` for `800W` answer I have to find all answers between steps above and below and re-interpolate all user-inserted answers??? C'mon it's not a Facebook app, I'm working on energetic certification tool for an authority...

Comment: @neurino: Why can't you  prevent duplicates?  You should have exactly one `Answer(input=800W, score=3)` row in the database.

Comment: @S.Lott: yes **and** I should update also score for user inserted value `850W` since it would not be `2` anymore, and so on for all users inserted answers... simply it's not appllicable.